# Sumar diferencias entre 6 fechas PHP, laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server

Tengo esto: Que me permite traer todos los registros de esta tabla que básicamente trae los campos que quiero operar en este caso , pero con este código solo me esta permitiendo sumar solo 1 comparación en este caso la última : fecha_entrada1,fecha_entrada2,fecha_entrada3,fecha_salida1,fecha_salida2,fecha_salida3 de tipo datetime en una db SQL server, necesito realizar 3 comparaciones(fecha_entrada1 vs fecha_salida1, et.c) y sumar estas tres comparaciones en horas y mostrarlas en un archivo que estoy generando en excel.

```
public function excel1() {
//        Excel::create('Registros-Excel', function($excel) {
//            $excel->sheet('registros', function($sheet) {
        $dteDiff = new DateTime("0000-00-00 00:00:00");
        $rr = DB::table('registros')->get();
                foreach ($rr as  $key){
                    $dt = new DateTime($key->fecha_entrada1);
                    $dt1 = new DateTime($key->fecha_salida1);
                    $dt2 = new DateTime($key->fecha_entrada2);
                    $dt3 = new DateTime($key->fecha_salida2);
                    $dt4 = new DateTime($key->fecha_entrada3);
                    $dt5 = new DateTime($key->fecha_salida3);
                    $interval = date_diff($dt,$dt1);
                    $interval = date_diff($dt2,$dt3);
                    $dteDiff->add($interval);
                    var_dump($dteDiff->format('h'));
                    // $interval = date_diff($dt,$dt1) + date_diff($dt2,$dt3);
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto funcionó para mí:

```
foreach ($rr as $key) {
            $dt = new DateTime($key->fecha_entrada1);
            $dt1 = new DateTime($key->fecha_salida1);
            
            $dt2 = new DateTime($key->fecha_entrada2);
            $dt3 = new DateTime($key->fecha_salida2);
            
            $dt4 = new DateTime($key->fecha_entrada3);
            $dt5 = new DateTime($key->fecha_salida3);
            
            $diff1 = $dt->diff($dt1);
            $diff2 = $dt2->diff($dt3);
            $diff3 = $dt4->diff($dt5);
            $horastotales = intval($diff1->h) + intval($diff2->h) + intval($diff3->h);
            echo $horastotales;
}
```